longtable doesn't respond to \setlength, fit on same page as section header
I want a table that gives an overview of the data I am working with. The table is in the appendix and as it is very wide it needs to fill the whole page. I managed to fit it within the margins, but it is still too wide to fit on the same page as the section header. The header should be in portrait orientation, while the table is rotated by 90°. What happens is that the header is on top of a blank page and the table follows on the two subsequent pages. I want the first part of the table to be on the same page with the section header.
This is an extract of the Latex-code I have written so far:

\documentclass[stu, a4paper, floatsintext]{apa7}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa, doi=false, natbib=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}


\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\shorttitle{a very loooooooooooooooooooong title as is spans over two lines in the header}


\begin{document}

\section{Summary table\label{app:bigtable}}

\begin{landscape}
\tiny
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llcclll}
\caption{Characteristics and moderator variables of the 19 studies included in the meta-analysis.} \\
\toprule
 & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Moderators} & \\
 \cline{3-6}
\makecell[tl]{Author(s) \\ Year} & Population & \makecell[tl]{Measurement of Power Dynamics \\ (Bias)} & \makecell[tl]{Measurement of Consent Behavior \\ (Bias)} & \makecell[tl]{Role in \\ Consent-making} & Sexual orientation & \makecell[tl]{statistical measure \\ N° dSS} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\makecell[tl]{Author(s) \\ Year} & Population & \makecell[tl]{Measurement of Power Dynamics \\ (Bias)} & \makecell[tl]{Measurement of Consent Behavior \\ (Bias)} & Role in Consent-making & Sexual orientation & \makecell[tl]{statistical measure \\ N° dSS} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\textit{Note:} & \multicolumn{5}{r}{\makecell[tr]{Convenience sample of university students \\ Sampling method not specified \\ Validated tool of measurement \\ Number of dependent subsamples \\ standardized $\beta$ \\ non-standardized $\beta$}} & \makecell[tr]{'*' \\ '\textsuperscript{NA}' \\ '{\l}' \\ N° dSS \\ std. $\beta$ \\ non-std. $\beta$} \\
\endlastfoot

\makecell[tl]{Barbaro, Holub \& Shackelford \\ 2018} & \makecell[tl]{125 women and 159 men \\ Age $M=31.9$ $(SD=8.6)$ \\ Ethnicity: divers} & \makecell[tl]{Attachment style \\ (bilateral)} & \makecell[tl]{Coercion \\ (other)} & Receiver & heterosexual & \makecell[tl]{$r$ \\ 2} \\

\label{bigtable}
\end{longtable} 
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

I tried fitting the table using
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}[H]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}llcclll}

which did nothing to the table until I set the font to \tiny.
Changing the length specified in the \setlength command doesn't do anything for values > 0. I tried removing @{\extracolsep{\fill}} which also had no effect. It feels like a bit of luck whether \setlength responds. I tried shortening column headers for columns 5 and 6, which also didn't return the desired outcome.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets be compilable resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Do you like to have section title and table on the same (portrait oriented) page, where table had to be rotated for 90 degree? Or the section tile should be rotated to, i.e. it is inside landscape as table is? Please elaborate.

The code you've posted doesn't compile, in part because there's no \begin{document} directive. Please make the necessary edits to make your code actually compilable.

Note that longtable doesn't have an optional argument and it doesn't float, so no [H] is needed.

Thank you for your responses so far! I made the neccesary edits to my initial question.

If you like to have long table in landscape orientation, than in the case, when you like to have section title on the same page where table begin, than section title also should be in in landscape page.
Simpler code (to my opinion) you can get with use of tabularray package and for columns use X types as is shown in MWE (Minimal Working Example) below:
\documentclass[a4paper]{apa7}%[, a4paper, floatsintext]
\usepackage{geometry}

\shorttitle{Short}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=apa, doi=false, natbib=true
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, 
              singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\section{Summary table}
\label{app:bigtable}

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \footnotesize
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Characteristics and moderator variables of the 19 studies included in the meta-analysis.},
  label = {longtblr:bigtable},
remark{Note} = {{\\Convenience sample of university students.\\ 
                Sampling method not specified.\\ 
                Validated tool of measurement.\\ Number of dependent subsamples: standardized $\beta$, non-standardized $\beta$}; \medskip\newline
               {'*' \\ 
                '\textsuperscript{NA}' \\ 
                '{\l}' \\ 
                N° dSS \\ 
                std. $\beta$ \\ 
                non-std. $\beta$} 
                }
                ]{colsep = {3pt},
                  colspec={@{} X[l] X[1.2,l] *{4}{X[0.9,l]} X[0.7,l] @{}},
                  cell{1}{1,2,Z} = {r=2}{},
                  cell{1}{3} = {c=4}{c},
                  rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
{Author(s)\\ Year} 
    &   Population 
        &   Moderators
            &   &   &   &   {statistical measure \\ N° dSS}     \\
    \midrule
    &   &   {Measurement of Power Dynamics\\ (Bias)} 
            &   {Measurement of Consent Behavior \\ (Bias)} 
                &   {Role in \\ Consent-making}
                    &   Sexual orientation      
                        &                                       \\                        
    \midrule
{Barbaro, Holub \& Shackelford \\ 2018} 
    &   {125 women and 159 men \\ Age $M=31.9$ $(SD=8.6)$ \\ Ethnicity: divers} 
        &   {Attachment style \\ (bilateral)} 
            &   {Coercion \\ (other)} 
                &   Receiver 
                    &   heterosexual 
                        &   {$r$ \\ 2} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr} 
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}

Table in above MWE exploit all available space on page, can span number of pages and automatically insert continue at repeated caption and *continue on next page at bottom of all table parts except last one..

As you can see, I a wee bit reformat your note below table (it will appear after last part of table). To may opinion it is a bit strange formatted and so far is not visible any connection to table content. So I mostly left it as you write in your MWE.

Thank you for your swift response! As @Zarko pointed out, I forgot to add some information: I need the header to be in portrait mode, while the table is rotated by 90°. I reviewed the reformatting of the "Note" section and unfortunately that doesn't work for me. It has to be formatted the way I have it so far.

Than it seems that my answer doesn't help you. Actually, as I can conclude from your response,  you not even read it carefully, since than you should know, that your demand, as can be now understand from your question, i.e. section title in portrait orientation to which immediately  follow long table in landscape orientation, is not possible. Environment landscape always start at new page. Regarding table notes, you still wrote them on your (to my opinion awful) way.
